# How can I compile an Android project using Dagger 2 and DataBinding

Tags: android, gradle, data-binding, dagger-2

I am trying to use databinding and Dagger 2 (version 2.11 with the new Android Injection capabilities). If I take out databinding from my project then my Dagger 2 set up works fine. If I take out Dagger 2 then my databinding set up works fine.

My dagger dependencies are as follows:

```
compile "com.google.dagger:dagger-android-support:2.11"
apt "com.google.dagger:dagger-compiler:2.11"
apt "com.google.dagger:dagger-android-processor:2.11"
```

When I try to build I get the following error during the compile task:

```
> java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.google.common.base.Preconditions.checkState(ZLjava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/Object;Ljava/lang/Object;Ljava/lang/Object;)V
```

It looks like the issue is related to a Guava dependency (the Dagger 2 compiler and processor both depend on com.google.guava:guava:21.0), and if I explicitly list this dependency in my app build.gradle:

```
compile 'com.google.guava:guava:21.0'
```

...then the project will now compile. But it appears guava 21 is compiled using Java 8 and I now get the following error when trying to run the app:

```
Error:Error converting bytecode to dex:
Cause: Dex cannot parse version 52 byte code.
This is caused by library dependencies that have been compiled using Java 8 or above.
```

There is now an android compatible version of guava:

```
compile 'com.google.guava:guava:22.0-android'
```

But if I add this to my dependencies then Dagger 2 code generation no longer works:

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.google.common.collect.SetMultimap.forEach(Ljava/util/function/BiConsumer;)
```

Is anyone able to suggest a solution for this?

Answer (score 1):

Seems I rather overcomplicated things. Upgrading just the apt guava dependency resolved the issue. My final config was:

```
compile "com.google.dagger:dagger-android-support:2.11"
apt "com.google.dagger:dagger-compiler:2.11"
apt "com.google.dagger:dagger-android-processor:2.11"
apt 'com.google.guava:guava:22.0'
```